# В чем преимущество интерпретируемых языков перед компилируемыми?

Tags: python, c++, компилятор, интерпретатор

Википедия говорит например что преимущества это

1. кроссплатформенность
2. пошаговое отслеживание (отладка)
3. динамическая типизация

Вроде бы все абсолютно логично но можно предположить что мы можем перед выполнением компилируемой программы просто собирать ее т.е. грубо говоря вместо команды выполнения будет команды сборки+выполнения
из этого предположения следую вопросы к этим пунктам

1. Если мы однажды должны установить интерпретатор по нашу ос+архитектуру и т.п. почему мы не можем установить компилятор так же под нашу ос и собирать каждый раз проект из исходников например с++
2. На данный момент мы же можем отлаживать код С++ пошагово? не совсем понимаю этот пункт
3. Вроде бы динамическая типизация жестко не привязана к интерпретируемым языкам т.е. может быть реализована и в компилируемых?

И будет ли компиляция+запуск дольше чем интерпретация? т.е. можно ли говорить о том что из этого быстрее?

Comment: Хоть бы ссылку дали на статью, написанную невесть кем, в источнике надёжнейших знаний wiki.
И наверняка там ссылки на источники данных высказываний есть. Посмотрите их. Коротко: 1. Можем, полагаю. 2. Разумеется, есть пошаговая отладка везде. 3. Не привязана. За 30 сек гуглится. Objective-C - компилируемый с динамической типизацией. 4. Компиляторы быстрее интерпретаторов.

Comment: Быстрота  и эффективность зависит от того, что делаете. У каждого языка свое преимущество, и нужно применить этот язык там, где он более подходящий. Что сказано в википедии , все так и есть, но для ответа на все ваши вопросы нужен хороший сочинитель.  Когда то у нас был такой _ AnT

Comment: Крупные проекты могут компилироваться часами.

Comment: @Сергей https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: *`"И будет ли компиляция+запуск дольше чем интерпретация?"`* -- зависит от количества действий, которое выполняет итоговая программа. Если их мало, то чистая интерпретация будет быстрее. Начиная с какого-то количества, последующий выигрыш в скорости native code превысит затраты на его генерацию и компиляцию

Comment: JIT-компиляция окончательно порвёт шаблон

Comment: там сказано " значительно легче реализовать в интерпретаторе, чем в компиляторе", а не "невозсожно в компиляторе"

Comment: Интерпретация это выполнение кода, который создаётся динамически, и который вообще никогда не компилируется. Это создаёт гибкость кода, если вы только умеете и вам это нужно. Скорость выполнения чуток помедленнее. Преимущество в том, что всё это уже используется и с успехом. **PHP**, **Java**, **JavaScript** и т.д. Нет смысла компилировать код веб страницы, которую вызовут пару раз в год, и его постоянно модифицируют.

Comment: *`"Вроде бы динамическая типизация жестко не привязана к интерпретируемым языкам т.е. может быть реализована и в компилируемых?"`* -- ну, если она в самом деле динамическая (т.е. тип не может быть определен по предшествующим описаниям во время компиляции), то ничего кроме интерпретации (в коде, создаваемом компилятором) придумать не удастся

Comment: Все популярные интерпретируемые языки сдержат фазу компиляции в промежуточный код, который затем интерпретируется. Почти все компилируемые языки можно скомпилировать в сборку для исполнения (интерпретации) на JavaScript машине. Язык Lisp компилируется и его система исполнения содержит полноценный компилятор. Разделение "интерпретируемый/компилируемый" устарело. Существенная вещь только одна: можно ли вызвать компилятор во время работы программы.

Comment: О, я когда-то тут отвечал на эту тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/904210/213977 : считайте сравнение JS и C++ .

Comment: А все же почему во многих источниках упоминается пошаговая отладка в интерпретируемых языках именно , в компилируемых это раньше не работало ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe это понятно, но это скорее следствие использования интерпретируемого языка. Я как раз и спрашиваю в чем принципиальное преимущество перед тем чтобы запустить вместо выполнения скрипта сразу компиляцию+выполнения. Если представить что у нас есть файл python и файл c++, но с++ мы не компилируем отдельно, а в одной команде и билд и запуск.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy согласен, но меня скорее интересует изначально почему возникло это разделение и в чем реально было преимущество.

Comment: Разделение чисто историческое/технологическое. Первые интерпретируемые языки не проводили компиляцию ([BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC)). Первые компилируемые языки порождали машинный код в один проход, без введения промежуточного представления ([Fortran](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD), [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language))). В таких языках можно найти конструкции непосредственно связанные с архитектурой и системой команд процессоров.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> В чем преимущество интерпретируемых языков перед компилируемыми?
>
> Википедия говорит например что преимущества это
>
> кроссплатформенность

[Java](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java) - кроссплатформенный компилируемый язык со строгой типизацией.

> пошаговое отслеживание (отладка)

Компиляция препятствует отладке и в интерпретируемых языках. Сложные вложенные [list comprehensions](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) с генераторами сложно отлаживать пошагово потому что это сложные конструкции со сложными правилами (хотя они хотят выглядеть легкими и приятными).

> динамическая типизация

[Lisp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF) компилируется в машинный код и у него динамическая типизация. В компилируемом языке [Julia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) динамическая типизация, а компилятор порождает столько вариантов процедуры, сколько будет вариантов типов входных параметров для неё.

> Вроде бы все абсолютно логично но можно предположить что мы можем
> перед выполнением компилируемой программы просто собирать ее т.е.
> грубо говоря вместо команды выполнения будет команды сборки+выполнения
> из этого предположения следую вопросы к этим пунктам
>
> Если мы однажды должны установить интерпретатор по нашу ос+архитектуру и т.п. почему мы не можем установить компилятор так же
> под нашу ос и собирать каждый раз проект из исходников например с++

Всё так и есть, разницы почти нет. Существенная разница такая: [Python](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python) имеет встроенный компилятор (можно исполнить код из текста), [C++](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) не имеет. Но есть компилируемые языки со встроенными компиляторами - [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)).

> На данный момент мы же можем отлаживать код С++ пошагово? не совсем понимаю этот пункт

Можете, если не применяли агрессивные оптимизации. Чем сильнее оптимизируется код, тем слабее соответствие между исходным кодом и машинными инструкциями. Замечу что для [C](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) есть чистые интерпретаторы, хотя они мало полезны в отладке из-за недостаточной переносимости языка.

> Вроде бы динамическая типизация жестко не привязана к интерпретируемым языкам т.е. может быть реализована и в компилируемых?

Да, примеры были выше.

> И будет ли компиляция+запуск дольше чем интерпретация? т.е. можно ли
> говорить о том что из этого быстрее?

Обычно интерпретаторы стартуют быстрее потому что у них простые компиляторы без глубоких оптимизаций. Но [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)) компилировался в машинный код ([Turbo Pascal](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Pascal)). Исходный код Паскаля рассчитан на однопроходную компиляцию. IDE работала быстрее чем QBasic.

Разделение интерпретатор/компилятор имеет исторические корни. Первые интерпретируемые языки не проводили компиляцию ([BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC)). Сам язык BASIC со строчно-ориентированным синтаксисом разработан для построчной интерпретации.

Компилятор ТурбоПаскаля порождал машинный код в один проход, без введения промежуточного представления чтобы расходовать меньше памяти (он вообще весь работал в памяти без обращения к диску - диском была медленная дискета).

Позже, когда памяти и процессора стало больше, компиляторы и интерпретаторы стали заимствовать технологии друг у друга. Всё смешалось.

Предлагаю другую классификацию: динамическая/статическая типизация и возможность исполнения произвольного кода во время исполнения программы.